# How do I return a color method while using loops in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, return

```
public Color determineColor(char guessLetter, int index) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LETTERS; i++) {
        if (guessLetter == secretWord.charAt(index)) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        }
        else if(guessLetter == secretWord.charAt(i)) {
            return Color.YELLOW;
        }
        else {
            return Color.GRAY;
        }
    }
    return Color;
}
```

I am trying to create a program similar to Wordle. This is one of the helper methods. This specific method loops through all the letters of an input and compares it to the letters of the "secret word." I am a newer coder and I am a bit stuck on how I am supposed to return the color based on the if-else statement within the loop. The method, as of now, is a syntax error. I know it has to do something with the variables scope. I tried defining "Color" as a global variable but the loop doesn't update variables outside of that loop of the same name so that is where I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: `Color` is a class as you have imported it. `return Color;` doesn't return a variable. Side note: the first `if`doesn't need to be in the loop, and the loop will always run only once as it returns in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of jhammon is very relevant.
Here is a piece of code that could help you.

```java
    public static Color determineColor(char guessLetter, int index) {
        if (guessLetter == secretWord.charAt(index)) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        } else if (secretWord.contains(guessLetter+"")) {
            return Color.YELLOW;
        }
        return Color.GRAY;
    }
```

The +"" is not necessarily very clean but it allows you to cast the char in string.